# Is there something wrong with the op amp circuit in this Element 14 YouTube vid?

Tags: operational-amplifier, bias

The video is [here](https://youtu.be/ASlecUcwXNY) with schematic at 3:20 and attached below.
There is no DC path to the non-inverting input, and the only DC route to the inverting input is via the output.

[image: Schematic here]

In fairness to the presenter at Element 14 he makes it clear that the the purpose of the complete circuit is to add distortion to an electric guitar by sending the signal through a 741 whose bad slew rate is a feature to help shape the tone. Also the purpose of the clamping diodes is to clip the signal above +/- 0.7 volts; the higher harmonics are removed at the next stage (not shown). The diodes are 1N4148 and the elctrolytics are 2.2uF.
Will the op amp work as drawn? If not what changes are needed?

Answer (score 0):

The + input of the opamp MUST be biased at half the supply voltage.
[image: opamp biasing]

Comment: Yes you're right! I can see what needs to be done to fix the schematic and I'll revert when I have the circuit working

Comment: Notice that R1 in the circuit I posted should be fed from a filtered voltage so that it does not feed power supply hum into the input of the opamp.